# rmmod: ERROR: Module vfio_pci is builtin

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, virtualization

I'm close to completing my definitive guide to pass through an nvidia device by loading and unloading the driver and it's dependencies such as vfio-pci from / to the vm and viceversa. I'm a step away because the binding works from the host to the vm,but not from the vm to the host. I have 3 graphic cards : 1) intel chipset integrated inside the mobo (gigabyte aorus pro + I9) ; 2) nvidia RTX 2080 ti ; 3) nvidia gtx 1060,running on Ubuntu 21.04. In a previous step I have assigned the devices below to vfio-pci :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti] [10de:1e04] (rev a1)

Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti] [19da:2503]

Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci

Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia


01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f7] (rev a1)

Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. TU102 High Definition Audio Controller [19da:2503]

Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci

Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


01:00.2 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB 3.1 Host Controller [10de:1ad6] (rev a1)

Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. TU102 USB 3.1 Host Controller [19da:2503]

Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci

Kernel modules: xhci_pci


01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB Type-C UCSI Controller [10de:1ad7] (rev a1)

Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. TU102 USB Type-C UCSI Controller [19da:2503]

Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci

Kernel modules: i2c_nvidia_gpu
```

The problem that I have arises when I try to remove the vfio-pci module :

```
rmmod vfio-pci :
```

it gives this error :

---> `rmmod: ERROR: Module vfio_pci is builtin`

**BEFORE TO BINDING THE NVIDIA DRIVER TO THE HOST,i NEED TO UNDERSTAND HOW TO UNLOAD THE VFIO_PCI MODULE,THAT SEEMS TO BE COMPILED INSIDE THE KERNEL,BUT IT SHOULDN'T BECAUSE I HAVE LOADED IT AS A MODULE AT THE BEGINNING,ADDING IT TO THE FILE /ETC/MODULES :

```
/etc/modules :


vfio

vfio_iommu_type1

vfio_pci

kvm

kvm_intel

kvmgt

xengt

vfio-mdev
```

INFACT YOU CAN SEE WHAT'S THE PROBLEM THAT FREEZES IT :

```
#dpkg -S vfio-pci.ko

linux-image-5.8.18-acso: /lib/modules/5.8.18-acso/kernel/drivers/vfio/pci/vfio-pci.ko
```

It is bound to a kernel that I use in certain circumstances,when I want to use the audio device in the HOST os and not on the VM. I would like to understand how I can unbind it.

Comment: Whatever the underlying issue is, shouldn't it be enough to unbind the device you care about from vfio-pci? Per https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vfio.txt that should be like "echo ssss:bb:dd.f > /sys/bus/pci/devices/ssss:bb:dd.f/driver/unbind"